# Passing a variable to javascript regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to pass a variable to my javascript regular expression, but it returns null all the time. Regular expression is correct, but, Im unable to execute it on the JS. Below is my code:

```
'use strict';

  function matchExp(val) {
    let text = 'Is this " all": there is?';
    var match_pat = '[^"]* all\b[^"]*("\s*:)'
    var regMatch = new RegExp(match_pat, 'g');
    return(text.match(regMatch))
  }

  console.log(matchExp())
  module.exports = {
    matchExp
  }
```

```
**Expected Result**: "all":
```

Comment: Why are you so sure that "Regular expression is correct"? Looks very confusing to me. If you replaced your `match_pat` with e.g. "all", it would work correctly, so how come you are so sure that it is correct?

Comment: I need to match it with the quote(""). I know the regex is right because I already tested it on regex101 and also if I put the regex directly into the code without the variable,  it works.

Comment: You have to double escape the backslashes in the RegExp constructor, but you can also use a literal and you can remove the capture group for a match only `var match_pat = /[^"]* all\b[^"]*"\s*:/;` and `return(text.match(match_pat)[0]);` (first check if you have a match)

Comment: `const match_pat = \`"* +${val} *"*\`;`